# How can I iterate through each line of a file using each line to replace a string in other files, creating a new file each time

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have file 1 which contains:

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
```

I have file 2 which contains:

```
11111 22222 33333
```

and file 3 which contains:

```
22222 11111 33333
```

I want to insert each line in file 1 into file 2 and 3 replacing '11111' and creating a new file each time.
So the end result is 4 files:

File 1:

```
AAAAAA2222233333
```

File 2:

```
BBBBBB2222233333
```

File 3:

```
22222AAAAAA33333
```

File 4:

```
22222BBBBBB33333
```

I have attempted to use a nested for loop and sed to replace the values, at the moment I have this; however, it does not work:
(directory/* contains file 2 and file 3)

```
FILES=/directory/*
cat file1 | while read line ;do
    for f in $FILES; do

            cat $f | sed 's/11111/$i/g' > newfiles/$f$i.txt

    done

done
```

Each time I run the script there may be a different number of files to edit, so I would like to iterate over the directory to make sure all files are covered. There will also be different numbers of strings in file 1.

Comment: There will be a different number of files in the directory at each time, so i require the script to itterate through all files in the directory. Also, the format of each file may be different so i think sed replace is suitable.

Comment: And why are file1 and file2 the same and file3 and file4 the same? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need to do.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, i have corrected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the substitution file and then loop the target files. I think you are almost there. I have something like the following (I subbed some file names so that the globbing would work):

```
!/bin/bash

i=1
FILES=./other_file*
while read r; do
    for f in $FILES; do
        sed "s/11111/$r/g" > newfiles/file$i.txt < $f
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
done <file1
```

Here we first indicate that we are using bash as the shell. Then set a counter `i` to 1. Next `glob` the files into a variable. The loop through file1 and assign each line to variable `r`. Then for each of the files sub the `11111` string with whatever we saw in the line. Output it to a new file using the counter in the name and then increment the counter. Repeat until the loops are done.

Answer (score 2):

How about Awk? save the mappings from `file1` into an associative array, and then loop over the array for each line of the other files:

```
awk -v OFS= '
  NR==FNR {t[NR]=$0; next} 
  {s = $0} 
  {
    for(i in t) {
      $0 = s; 
      sub(/11111/,t[i]); 
      $1=$1; 
      print > "newfile" ++n
    }
  }' file1 file2 file3
```

(the `OFS=` and `$1=$1` are just to force the record to be re-evaluated with en empty field separator, so as to remove the spaces between fields). Results:

```
$ head newfile*
==> newfile1 <==
AAAAAA2222233333

==> newfile2 <==
BBBBBB2222233333

==> newfile3 <==
22222AAAAAA33333

==> newfile4 <==
22222BBBBBB33333
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below script to achieve the same

```
for i in `cat mainfile`; do sed "s/11111/$i/g" file1 |sed -r "s/\s+//g" >file1_$i; sed "s/11111/$i/g" file2|sed -r "s/\s+//g" >file2_$i;done
```

output

Please find the output of all 4 files

```
AAAAAA2222233333
============================
BBBBBB2222233333
============================
22222AAAAAA33333
============================
22222BBBBBB33333
==========================
```

==